# Let (X, d) be a metric space and let A be a subset of X and O be an open subset of X. Prove that $O \cap \overline{A} \subseteq \overline{O\cap A}$

Tags: real-analysis

I don't know how to use the fact that O is open. Its interior must be itself, so I guess I should take the complement of the sets in question. But I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x \in O \cap \overline{A}$. This means that $x \in O$ and $x \in \overline{A}$. Suppose $B$ is any open ball containing $x$, then $O \cap B$ is also open (this is where we use $O$ is open) and contains $x$, and as $x \in \overline{A}$, we know that $(B \cap O) \cap A \neq \emptyset$. But this means that $B \cap (O \cap A) \neq \emptyset$ as well and as $B$ was arbitrary, $x \in \overline{O \cap A}$, as required to prove the inclusion.

Comment: I don't really follow the statement that $(B \cap O) \cap A \neq \emptyset$. Could you explain that a bit?

Comment: couldn't x be in closure of A but not in A?

Comment: $x \in \overline{A}$ iff every open set (or open ball) that contains $x$ intersects $A$. $B \cap O$ is such an open set, and we know $x \in \overline{A}$ from the start @davidh

Comment: I see. So, for the last bit, because B is arbitrary, we invoke the iff condition for closedness on $O \cap A$ right?

Comment: @davidh yes we use both directions.